# Fake infinite scroll (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a `<table>` with many rows (about 10.000) but i just want to display the first 20 rows when i visit the page and when i scroll to the bottom of the table i want to display the next 20 records and so on. I dont want to use ajax, because i load the whole data when i load the page. All the infinite scroll plugins i saw just worked with ajax.
Do you know a fast and easy solution?

I already tried the Plugin jscroll, but it's only working with ajax!

Thank you!

Comment: Does this have to be a javascript solution - this looks solvable with just CSS?

Comment: Loading and hiding 10000 rows will almost certainly slow down your page to near unusable. You should use ajax

Comment: google for `fake ajax` better. W/o relation to scroll.

Comment: The reason all the solutions are ajax is because you really don't want to try to load 10,000 rows in one hit.  The browser will freeze for some time while it tries to render all those rows (prev experience shows IE could take up to 5 mins for this!).

Comment: Question: If you've already loaded the data, why wouldn't you just show it all to the user?  Then they won't get that clunky feel of trying to scroll to the bottom and the scroll bar keeps resizing/jumping back up.

Comment: I ask to see if this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any lib or extensions which could do what you're asking, but you can try to make your own script because this is a particular case.

---

I'll try to build a JS function to display N rows at time.

Using a table like so:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  ...
</table>
```

start hiding all the rows with `display: none;` in your CSS

```
#myTable tr{ display: none; }
```

now we have to write a function which shows N rows at time

```
function showRows(_max){
    $("#myTable tr").each(function(_ind, _el){
        if (_ind >= showRows.current && _ind < showRows.current +_max) $(_el).show();
    });
    showRows.current += _max;
}
showRows.current = 0;
```

The next step is to use this method in your scroll event when it reach the bottom

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()){
        showRows(20);   // 20 is the next number of elements to display
    }
});
```

That's all I guess,
Here the [***DEMO***](https://jsfiddle.net/up727bxv/)

---

The code of `showRows()` above isn't optimized (for performance) but should still work fine and fast.
Otherwise replace it with this which should be ALOT faster:

```
function showRows(_max){ 
    var rows = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (var ind = showRows.current, ln = rows.length; ind < ln; ind++){
        if ( ind < showRows.current+_max) rows[ind].style.display = "table-row";
        else break;
    }
    showRows.current += _max;
}
showRows.current = 0;
```